# displaying parse get as a string (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

my problem is as follow:

The following is not being displayed

```
    alert(object.get('user_code'));
```

I know the code ran because i've place log next to, where it indicate the console log ran 29 times due to 29 instance of the object but the alert doesnt display

The reason i need this as a string because I will compare it to see if 'user_'code' match the current user code being generated (string), if it matches than a new one will be produced until no match is found.

```
 var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);


  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
          console.log('2');

    //  alert("hi");
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            console.log('3');

        var object = results[i];
        alert(object.get('user_code'));

      }


    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
```

Comment: did you try .toString()

Comment: Which console log is firing? Are you sure results isn't empty?

Comment: undefined that what the alert give

Comment: Is the value of `object` defined? Can you log that to console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
alert(object.get('user_code'));
```

To

```
alert(object['user_code']);
```

If you look at the console log, you should see an "Uncaught TypeError: object.get is not a function" error. If it still doesn't work, then check if the object is not null or undefined.